# Why does \mathrm give an error?

Tags: amsmath, italic, mathrm

I am trying to use \mathrm to remove the italics from an equation as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{tr}(A)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode.
```

How can I remove the italics in the equation?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you're using a template that somebody passed to you. Most of those “templates” are full of dubious redefinitions of important commands, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: When I extend your code fragment to make it [minimally compilable](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) -- basically, by prefixing `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}` and by affixing `\end{document}` -- I am *unable to reproduce the error message* you say you're getting. The only possible inference is that your document executes some (until now) undisclosed instructions that redefine `\mathrm`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @JosephWright Doing as suggested, I realized that the problem is that the package gb4e makes rmmath give the error message above. I can just remove the package and my document will work. Should I edit the answer to show this? Make a new answer (since the other one is downvoted)? Delete the question alltogether?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gb4e` package seems completely broken, I would avoid using it but defining `\new@fontshape` (to anything) will at least stop it completely breaking math font changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{tr}(A)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

runs without error.

Answer (score 8):

In `gb4e.sty` we find

```
% For any REALLY old distributions without \rmfamily
\@ifundefined{rmfamily}{\let\rmfamily=\rm \let\bfseries=\bf}

\@ifundefined{new@fontshape}{\def\reset@font{}\let\mathrm\rmfamily\let\mathit\mit}{}
```

which used to work until approximately 2015, when a new release of LaTeX removed the internal command `\new@fontshape`.

In `source2e.pdf` dated 2011/06/27 we find

[image]

which shows that looking for `\new@fontshape` was already wrong in 2010 when the `gb4e` package was last updated. It worked for some time and the bug went undiscovered because apparently nobody used `\mathrm` together with `gb4e` before today.

The `latexrelease` method

```
\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
```

unfortunately only works if `amsmath` is not loaded (because there's no rollback for it to that date).

So the only method is to provide a definition for `\new@fontshape` before loading `gb4e`:

```
\ExpandArgs{c}\providecommand{new@fontshape}{}
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

Complain with the maintainer.

By the way, if you plan to use math together with `gb4e`, it's better to issue `\noautomath` before `\begin{document}` or you risk other weird errors.