Cyrillic Italicization error for Times New Roman font from times package
I have problem with italicization using \let\eachwordone=\it for Times New Roman font from \usepackage{times}. Here is my tex document:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{times}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 
 \let\eachwordone=\it
 
 \noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex % Glosa 1
{\bf(Strategi praanggapan = \textnormal{\textsc{pgp}})}
\glll \?{Геи} \?{всë} \?{равно} \?{пришли} — \?{вопреки} \?{запрету} \\
gei vsë ravno prišli — vopreki zapretu \\
gay semua dengan.sama\textsc{.pgp} pergi\textsc{.pgp} — meskipun larangan\textsc{.pgp} \\
\trans “Para kelompok gay, bagaimanapun, tetap pergi, meskipun terdapat larangan” \\

\end{exe}

\end{document}

Resulting typset:

As seen from the typeset, it did not italicize the first line of the gloss (the Russian Cyrillic text). Using the code below did not work either in italicizing the fonts:
\texit{\?{Геи} \?{всë} \?{равно} \?{пришли} — \?{вопреки} \?{запрету}}

The italicization still works, however, when the the default font is used:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 
 \let\eachwordone=\it
 
 \noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex % Glosa 1
{\bf(Strategi praanggapan = \textnormal{\textsc{pgp}})}
\glll \?{Геи} \?{всë} \?{равно} \?{пришли} — \?{вопреки} \?{запрету} \\
gei vsë ravno prišli — vopreki zapretu \\
gay semua dengan.sama\textsc{.pgp} pergi\textsc{.pgp} — meskipun larangan\textsc{.pgp} \\
\trans “Para kelompok gay, bagaimanapun, tetap pergi, meskipun terdapat larangan” \\

\end{exe}

\end{document}


How can I improve my tex document so that it italicizes the Times New Roman fonts from \usepackage{times}using \let\eachwordone=\it?

Off-topic: left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm may be expressed more compactly as margin=3cm.

The times package doesn't support Cyrillic.
I suggest to use \usepackage{newtx} and to substitute the font family for Cyrillic with Tempora, which supports Cyrillic and is Times-based as well.
Please, note that \it and \bf have been deprecated for about thirty years.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\providecommand{new@fontshape}{}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{amssymb}% not with newtx
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}


\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\noautomath


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\RenewCommandCopy{\eachwordone}{\itshape}
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex % Glosa 1
{\bfseries(Strategi praanggapan = \textnormal{\textsc{pgp}})}
\glll \?{Геи} \?{всë} \?{равно} \?{пришли} — \?{вопреки} \?{запрету} \\
gei vsë ravno prišli — vopreki zapretu \\
gay semua dengan.sama\textsc{.pgp} pergi\textsc{.pgp} — meskipun larangan\textsc{.pgp} \\
\trans “Para kelompok gay, bagaimanapun, tetap pergi, meskipun terdapat larangan” \\

\end{exe}

\end{document}



on newfontshape see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709602/1090

or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709605/1090 if you prefer:-)

Thank you, it works @egreg!
